# Conditional Maven build command on Travis CI using Regex

Tags: regex, maven, github, build, travis-ci

In my Travis CI script on Github, I have the following condition, where the `default` profile is run if commits are pushed to a remote branch. And `test` profile if it is a pull request.

```
script:
  - 'if [ "$TRAVIS_EVENT_TYPE" == "push" ]; then
      mvn clean install;
  else
      mvn clean install -P test;
  fi'
```

Now the problem I am facing is that *if* condition also runs when there is a merge from `feature` to `develop` branch which I do not want. I want the *if* condition to run only when there is a push from local `feature` or `bugfix` branch to remote. To handle this I have added regular expression to match the branches like below.

```
script:
  - 'if [ "$TRAVIS_EVENT_TYPE" == "push" && "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" =~ ^(feature|bugfix)]; then
      mvn clean install;
  else
      mvn clean install -P test;
  fi'
```

But it gives the following error:

> The command "if [ "$TRAVIS_EVENT_TYPE" == "push" && "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" =~ ^(feature|bugfix)]; then mvn clean install; else mvn clean install -P test; fi" exited with 1.

**Edit**: I think matching the branch condition won't help in achieving what I am trying to do here. Since the merge will be from `feature-*` or `bugfix-*` to `develop` branch. So I think this additional branch check is redundant  here.

So the build rules I am trying to implement are:

1. If it is a *commit push* from local branches to remote branches, then run the `default` profile with `mvn clean install`.
2. If it is a new *pull request* or pull request *merge*, then run the `test` profile with `mvn clean install -P test`

What will be the right checks to achieve this in Travis CI script?

Comment: Can you try inverting the if condition with `"$TRAVIS_EVENT_TYPE" == "pull_request"`?